# VBA When mouse hovers over a line and shows syntax what do bolded words imply?

Tags: excel, vba

I inherited a large workbook that I am making changes to.

(this is why I have to name things like eye instead of i because it has already been used)

I have a workbook, the first sheet is a summary sheet, each sheet after it has test data and a name, Im wanting to put a sparkline of data from each sheet by its corresponding name on the Summary page

```
Dim eye As Integer
For eye = 3 To LAstRow
 Range("E" & eye).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("E" & eye).Select
    Dim rangesForSparkLine
    Set rangesForSparkLine = Sheets(eye).Range("P3:P24")
   Range("E" & eye).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=rangesForSparkLine
```

As you can see, I was thinking of naming the range and using that for the source data.

The error I get is "Type Mis-match"

When I hover my mouse over it, I see 
[Add(Type As XlSparkType, **SourceData As String**)As SparklineGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTP45.png)

More important than how to get the code to work, I'd like to ask How do I interpret and use this "yellow mouse over box", is it exact placement on my screen showing me that my issue is directly above it, I imagine it is a syntax template.

Thank you in advance for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bolded line shows which bit is currently being a problem - in your example, **SourceData:=rangesForSparkLine**.

In this case, what it's telling you is that VBA is expecting a **String**.
What you're giving it is a **Range** object (i.e. not a **String**)
The solution would be to simply feed it the address as a **String** directly, or use the **.Address()** property for the **Range** object.

Comment: I have typed ?wrkb.Sheets(WSname).Range("P3:P" & Lrow).Address 
into the immeadiate window, it spits out $P$3:$P$61

So I changed the line to read 
wrkb.Sheets("Late").Range("E" & LRplusone).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:="$P$3:$P$61"

It still throws Application defined or object defined error

It looks like WSname is the active sheet, is there a requirement that the cell the sparkline goes into has to be the active sheet by chance?

Comment: If you haven't specified the sheet in the SourceData address (e.g. **"Sheetname!A1:B2"**, it'll default to the active sheet.
You'll have to check that all you parameters are valid - i.e. "Late" is a valid worksheet, that LRplusone resolves to a positive integer at this point in the code (or its text representation), etc.
It looks like you got past the Type Mismatch error; The 'application or object-defined error' in this context means you're referring to something that doesn't exist - e.g a misspelled worksheet, workbook, or range address.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to reference the range on the sheet using WS(WSname).range(P3:P61) As it turns out, the name of each sheet in this workbook occupies the same row, so I got to it by using

wrkb.Sheets("Late").Range("$E$" & LRplusone).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:="" & wrkb.Sheets("Late").Range("$E$" & LRplusone).Offset(0, -4).Value & "!P3:P" & Lrow

so my takeaway is "the string address of a range does not include worksheet objects" "Sheetname!A1:B2, not WS(WSnamevariable).range("A1:B2")  because the later is range object not a string

Answer (score 0):

The important part is here is the `SourceData AS String` bit. It's telling you that you must give it a string. Instead you're giving it a range. Those are very different types.

[Looking at the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sparklinegroups-add-method-excel) on the `.Add` method of the `SparklineGroup` object it reads, for this parameter

> Represents the range to use to create the sparkline.

So really you just need to get the Address for that Range and feed it into the `.Add()` method instead of the range object itself. Personally this seems really stupid as the argument SHOULD be a range... but I'm sure there is a method to the madness deep in the guts of excel and Microsofts design methodology around it's chart and data sources... right?

We can use the `.Address()` property of the `Range` object to have it spit back the address of the range as a `String` to make this thing happy (I think... I've not tested):

```
Range("E" & eye).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=rangesForSparkLine.Address
```

Comment: That above didn't work for me, Im going to work on it with that new understanding regarding the address

On a related note, I did find a less clean work-around. My first attempts involved copying and pasting a sparkline from the individual sheets to my summary sheet, but it looked very clunky and pixelated, 

But doing record Macro copy as picture and pasting, THEN editing that macro's last line

 ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False _
        , DisplayAsIcon:=True

making "as icon" True vice False is an improvement